# Why is preceding whitespace stripped out of chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

**Why is preceding whitespace stripped out of chat messages?** It makes explaining code tidbits much more difficult than it needs to be (especially for languages that depend on such formatting -- eg, Python).

---

*Context:*
I was just helping a user who had a [Django question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25332433/2456258), but discovered that the user was actually a few steps *behind* where his/her question would be relevant. So, we moved our comment-dialogue to chat and we cleared up the issue. However, this was a lot harder than it needed to be because the code-samples from the Docs that I/the user posted lost all formatting.

**Is there a reason that whitespace is removed?** Is it to dissuade users from using chat for this purpose?

Comment: This should only matter when you have a multiline message formatted as code. Does it still happen when you do that?

Comment: Yuppers -- lemme post a screenshot to clarify what I mean.

Comment: Look at [this message](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2317177#2317177) for an example of what I'm talking about.

Comment: Basically, chat messages are formatted as limited markdown. The markdown spec includes stripping extra whitespace. That's why there's a "fixed font" button.

Comment: Yeah, figured out the issue. If I include a non-code line (say a line that says "For example...") at the start, it sees the entire message as non-code. Definitely a foot-from-the-keyboard error. Should have realized that.

Answer (score 1):

**Oops... [User Error](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/28192/pebcak-error)**

If you include a non-code line at the beginning of the message, the *entire* message is seen as non-code and thus any preceding white-space is trimmed from the lines. If you *start* the meessage with code, then it's fine.

---

**Example 1:**

```
    def myFunc():
        return 2+2
```

... Is formatted as...

```
def myFunc():
    return 2+2
```

**Example 2:**

```
For example...

    def myFunc():
        return 2+2
```

... is formatted as....

```
For example...

def myFunc():
return 2+2
```